# Combine changes across files

Tags: git, git-diff

I come across this scenario often. I create `new_file.py` and move some or most of the code from `old_file.py` to it. After I stage both the files, I need to ensure that I haven't introduced any errors.

If I run `git diff`, I am shown the deleted lines in the old file (in red) and the added lines in new file (in green).

If these changes were in a single file, I could pass these options to git diff:

- `--word-diff` to ensure only the specific variable has been changed
- `--ignore-space-change` to ensure only indentation has changed

**How can I pass something similar to `--word-diff` or `--ignore-space-change` to the git diff?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and comparing directly the two files as they are on the filesystem, as opposed to comparing them against the git index:

```
git diff --no-index --ignore-space-change --word-diff --  old_file.py new_file.py
```

Answer (score 1):

If the files are staged then you can run: `git diff :old_file.py :new_file.py`

This should give you the diff between those 2 files in the staging area (note the ':' before the file names)